# list index out of range when iterating through a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

As you can see, the following array called `routine` has a series of other arrays inside of it.

```
[['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips'], [], [], [], ['Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], [], []]
```

I have tried to copy each item inside this array into a new array. However when i did so i got this output and the following error message.

```
Bench Press
Inner Chest Push
Smith Machine Bench Press
Cable Crossover
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Clearly the code works through the first array inside the 2d array, however stops after that.

This is the code used to generate the above error message.

```
newarray=[]
for x in range(len(routine)-1):
    for i in range(len(routine)-1):
        temp = routine[x][i]
        print (temp)
        newarray.append(temp)
```

Is there a way in which i can join up these arrays so that there is only one array that looks like this.

```
['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips','Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```

Comment: Think about len() for a second. It does not recurse into the elements, it just returns the length of the outer list. And yet you are using it for both your outer and inner loop.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested `list`s you can try using list comprehension:

```
routine = [['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips'], [], [], [], ['Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], [], []]
new_routine = [machine for machines in routine for machine in machines]
print(new_routine)
# ['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips', 'Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```

This only works if you have `list` of `lists` or two levels deep.

To change your code, we can do the following to obtain the same result:

```
newarray = []
for x in range(len(routine)):
    for i in range(len(routine[x])):
        newarray.append(routine[x][i])

print(newarray)
#['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips', 'Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```

Notice that I removed the `-1` from your code. `range(start, end)` goes from `start` to `end-1`aka the entire array since arrays start from `0`. That said, you don't need the `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
for e in routine:
    new_list += e
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
routine = [['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips'], [], [], [], ['Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], [], []]


newarray=[]
for i in routine:
        for ii in i:
                newarray.append(ii)

print(newarray) #Output: ['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips', 'Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use index. python can do it as simple as :

```
newlist=[]
for alist in routine:
    for element in alist:
        newlist.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

using [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
a=[['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips'], [], [], [], ['Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], [], []]
list(chain(*a))
```

Output

```
['Dumbell Press',
 'Chest Press Machine',
 'Smith Machine Bench Press',
 'Angled Dips',
 'Tricep Kickbacks',
 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested lists, a robust solution to combine all components into a single list can be done using [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
oldlist = [['Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Smith Machine Bench Press', 'Angled Dips'], [], [], [], ['Tricep Kickbacks', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], [], []]
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain.from_iterable(oldlist))
print(result)
#Output:
['Dumbell Press',
 'Chest Press Machine',
 'Smith Machine Bench Press',
 'Angled Dips',
 'Tricep Kickbacks',
 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions']
```